# How can I save Instagram stories in my media folder using media url?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-media, instagram-story

```
def save_media(story_id, media_url):
try:
    link = media_url[:media_url.find('?')]
    extension = link[::-1][:link[::-1].find('.')+1][::-1]
    if 'video' in media_url:
        extension = '.mp4'
        
    filepath = r'{0}\file path for media to save stories\{1}{2}'.format(os.getcwd(), story_id, extension)
    if not os.path.exists(filepath):
        response = requests.get(media_url)
        if response.status_code==200:
            with open(r'{}'.format(filepath), 'wb') as file:
                file.write(response.content)
            file.close()
    newpath = filepath.replace(f'{os.getcwd()}\\influnite', '')
    return newpath
except Exception as error:
    print('Error saving story media!')
    print(error)
    return ''
```

media url is fetched from api after running this code i am not getting media data(videos and stories) in media folder
someone can please tell what mistake am i doing?

Comment: You can, but you need to use selenium not pure python. remember instagram uses javascript to load it''s content.

Comment: https://github.com/pedromdpereira/Instagram-Downloader-Selenium

Comment: @EddwinPaz actually i have tried this one it is use to download photos but i need to download stories and videos

Comment: and i have did that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def save_media(story_id, media_url):
try:
    link = media_url[:media_url.find('?')]
    extension = link[::-1][:link[::-1].find('.')+1][::-1]
    if 'video' in media_url:
        extension = '.mp4'
        
    filepath = r'{0}/influnite/media/stories/{1}{2}'.format(os.getcwd(), story_id, extension)
    if not os.path.exists(filepath):
        response = requests.get(media_url)
        if response.status_code==200:
            with open(filepath, 'wb') as file:
                file.write(response.content)
            file.close()
    newpath = filepath.replace(r'{0}/influnite'.format(os.getcwd()), '')
    return newpath
except Exception as error:
    print('Error saving story media!')
    print(error)
    return ''
```

here first checked fetched that story is in `jpg` format or in `mp4` and after that it check for response from server and it save story and in file as `wb` i.e. write in bits and it save story in `media` folder